# Flask-RESTful alias

Tags: python, flask, flask-restful

I would like to create an alias between two resources.

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_restful import Api, Resource

class api_v1_help(Resource):
    def get(self):
        html_file = "API V1"
        return (html_file, 200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html; charset=utf-8'})

class api_v2_help(Resource):
    def get(self):
        html_file = "API V2"
        return (html_file, 200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html; charset=utf-8'})


app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)

# API (current)
api.add_resource(api_v1_help, '/api/help')

# API v1
api.add_resource(api_v1_help, '/api/v1/help')

# API v2
api.add_resource(api_v2_help, '/api/v2/help')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Start app
    app.run(debug=True,port=5000)
```

This is giving the following error : AssertionError: View function mapping is overwriting an existing endpoint function: api_v1_help

I can change the code like this :

```
api.add_resource(api_v1_help, '/api/help', '/api/v1/help')
```

but I would like to know if there is another solution with flask-restful to handle an alias by linking two API endpoints to the same function?

I search to group the calls for a specific API version.

Comment: Please make this an [minimally complete and then verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example. (minimum code to reproduce your issue.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`Flask.add_url_route`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/#flask.Flask.add_url_rule) instead:

```
# API v1
api.add_resource(api_v1_help, '/api/v1/help')

# API v2
api.add_resource(api_v2_help, '/api/v2/help')

# API (current)
app.add_url_rule('/api/help', endpoint='api_v1_help')
```

By default, `endpoint` is set as [the name of the view class](http://flask-restful-cn.readthedocs.io/en/0.3.4/api.html?highlight=regular%20expression#flask_restful.Api.add_resource), so you can use `'api_v1_help'` as the name after the `add_resource` call.